# Can we completely remove the WordPress Sitemaps (WordPress 5.5)?

Tags: plugins, php, posts, functions, theme-development

I have been using my WordPress site to create various types of content, I obviously submit my sitemaps to Google for getting my site indexed. But there is some content which I don't want on Google, and therefore don't want it in Sitemaps too.

I used to use a plugin to implement it, but now we have got overlapping functionalities, as WordPress supports sitemaps now.

So How can I either completely remove the WordPress sitemap, so that I just use the Plugin, and Google Search Console cant read my `wp-sitemap.xml`, OR selectively remove some posts from WordPress Sitemap, so that I can Customize Sitemap to my taste, and then remove the Sitemap Plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disabling the sitemap is easy, just add this line to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

Removing specific posts goes like this:

```
add_filter(
    'wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args',
    function( $args, $post_type ) {
        if ( 'post' !== $post_type ) {
            return $args;
        }
 
        $args['post__not_in'] = isset( $args['post__not_in'] ) ? $args['post__not_in'] : array();
        $args['post__not_in'][] = 123; // 123 is the ID of the post to exclude.
        return $args;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

There a quite a lot of ways to [customize the sitemap](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/22/new-xml-sitemaps-functionality-in-wordpress-5-5/) if you would rather use the WP native way than a plugin.

Comment: And what about having to do remove specific posts from the sitemaps, any way for that?

Comment: Added the post removal function. If you follow the link you'll see all the other options you have.

Comment: ... in addition  I think I would recommend having the disabler as a plugin rather than theme dependent.